How to Display Value From Separate Table on Razor Page Create.cshtml
I have a Create page to create data for my Supervisor model. It looks like this:

The Supervisor class is here:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Votes.Model
{
    public class Supervisor
    {
        [Key]
        public int SupervisorId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supervisor Last Name")]
        public string? SupLastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supervisor First Name")]
        public string? SupFirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ward")]
        public int? Ward { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "District")]
        public int? District { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Committee>? Committees { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Chair/Member Committee 1")]
        public string? MemberComm1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = " Chair/Member Committee 2")]
        public string? MemberComm2 { get; set; }
    }
}

public enum MemberComm1
{
    C,
    M,
    X
}

public enum MemberComm2
{
    C,
    M,
    X
}

Instead of the label for each MemberComm1 (Chair/Member Committee 1), MemberComm2 (Chair/Member Committee 2), etc, I would like to have the actual name of that committee (stored in the CommitteeDesc field).
Here is the Committee model:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Votes.Model
{
    public class Committee
    {
        [Key]
        public int CommitteeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Committee No")]
        public int CommitteeNo { get; set; }
       
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Committee Description")]
        public string? CommitteeDesc { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Committee Type")]
        public string? CommitteeType { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Supervisor> Supervisors { get; set; }
    }
}

Since the Committees each have a fixed CommitteeNo assigned to them (1, 2, etc), I would like to use some type of if statement to say if Committee.CommitteeNo == 1, then CommitteeDesc. I would just like to use this as a label (ie, 1 = Finance Committee, 2 = Govt Operations, etc. It would not be committed to any database table.
I have tried a variety of Lists, IEnumerables but I just can't figure out the syntax on the cshtml page.
Here is the .cs for the Create page as it is now.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Votes.Data;
using Votes.Model;
using System.Linq;

namespace Votes.Pages.Supervisors;

[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
    public Committee Committee { get; set; }

    public IList<Committee> CommitteeList { get; set; }

    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Committee> DisplayCommitteeData { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplayMunicipalityData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ward> DisplayWardData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<District> DisplayDistrictData { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await _db.Committee.Select(a => a.CommitteeId).ToListAsync();
        DisplayCommitteeData = await _db.Committee.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Municipality.Select(a => a.MunicipalityId).ToListAsync();
        DisplayMunicipalityData = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Ward.Select(a => a.WardId).ToListAsync();
        DisplayWardData = await _db.Ward.ToListAsync();
        await _db.District.Select(a => a.DistrictId).ToListAsync();
        DisplayDistrictData = await _db.District.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Supervisor.Add(Supervisor);
            await _db.Supervisor.AddAsync(Supervisor);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Supervisor added successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}

As you can see, I've got extra stuff I don't likely need. All in my attempts to get this to work. Can anyone please describe the direction I should be going? A frequent error I am getting is that the object cannot be null. There is full Committee data in the Committee table.
One thing I tried on the .cshtml page was:
@{
    var result = (from x in @Model.DisplayCommitteeData where x.CommitteeNo == 1 select x);
    {
        return result.ToString();
    }
}

Bur I keep getting an error on the word 'return' and I'm not sure what may go there instead.
Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

OK, after trying many different things for what is a simple answer (but still not simple for ME!), I hit upon that the label just like the field itself really needs an @foreach. Then I was able to use the IEnumerable I already had in place and use the following on my view page above each committee field:
                        @foreach (var item1 in Model.DisplayCommitteeData)
                        if (item1.CommitteeNo == 1)
                        {
                            @item1.CommitteeDesc;
                        }

I simply changed 'item1.CommitteeNo == 1) to 'item2.CommitteeNo ==2' etc for each of the committee fields. I then removed the label asp-for code lines as they were no longer needed.
